# how can i display only one recent product with all subcategories magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

On the category view page I'm getting id of all child categories.
I can display all the products of that category using category id. i have successfully got all product list using link below.
but i want to first recent product with subcategory.
Go through image to get better understanding.

[image]

here its view page of makeup category.and Concealers and foundation are chils category.
 i want first most recent product of child category.

here is code of view page.

```
<?php
        $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
        $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }
    ?>
    <div class="grid_24">
        <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h1 class="main-title"><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
    </div>


    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat){
            foreach($_subcat->getChildrenCategories() as $child){
            $cat_id=$child->getId();    

     ?>
            <div class="grid_12">
                <div class="category-wrapper">
                    <div class="ribbon">
                        <h2><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($child, $child->getName(), 'name') ?></h2>
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->load($cat_id);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>

    <?php } ?>    


        <a href="<?php echo $child->getUrl() ?>" id="<?php echo $cat_id;?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($child, $child->getName(), 'name') ?></a>

    <?php }}?>
```

Comment: And your code so far is?

Comment: Any try you have done ?

Comment: edited question with code. Right now I'm getting all products from category id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the product collection statement so it does what you want it to. By adding a limit, it will only bring out one product for that category (improve performance as well because you are loading one product and not all of them). You could then use the order statement maybe to pull out the newest product for that category.

```
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order('catalog_product_entity.entity_id DESC')->limit(1);
```

Basically with magento collections, providing you don't actually load the collection by calling the load method or start to loop through it, you can alter the sql to make it give you what you want. We did a similar thing to this years ago but by pulling out the most sold product within the category. Might want to add in block caching to your block and template if you have a large database of either categories or products.

A handy thing to do sometimes is;

```
var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString()); die();
```

Which will output the generated sql that will be executed and you can debug complex sql queries this way.

Comment: thanks for replaying Ashley Swatton.
but i am getting empty array after doing this.